# How to specify articles directory for middleman-blog?

Tags: middleman

Is it possible somehow to specify articles directory outside of source/? In data/articles/ for an instance. It would be quite convenient 'cause I'm using submodule repository inside data/ for data/content purposes.
I have this lines in my *config.rb*:

```rb
activate :blog do |o|
  o.permalink = "{title}"
  o.sources = "data/articles/{title}"
end
```

But thing still ain't working and `blog.articles` is empty. What I'm doing wrong? Or it is supposed to be so?